# Basic Double integration question

Tags: integration

If $\int{y dy} \int{xdx} = \int\int{xy dx dy} $

why isn't $\int{x dx} \int{x^2dx}= \int\int{xx^2 dx dx} = \int\int{x^3 dx dx}  $ ?

EDIT: I did try them with limits and still they gave different answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to simply be an issue with notation. In general, it is unclear whether
$$
\int y dy \int x dx
$$
means
$$
\left( \int y dy \right) \cdot \left( \int x dx \right)
$$
or
$$
\int x y dx dy
$$
since sometimes one might write
$$
\int x y dx dy = \int x dx \int y dy
$$
which appears to be the notation that you're using, but this is only in order to try to simplify integrating. In other words since $y$ does not depend on $x$ (or vice versa) we can pull out the $x$ from the *y-integral* and place it in the *x-integral*. Again this is simply to clarify and simplify multivariable integrals.

With this said let's discuss the second integral. Clearly you cannot be using the second notation above since $x$ clearly depends on $x$, so this must not actually be a double integral, but actually two single integrals multiplied together.

Comment: I am sorry.I fixed it now.

Comment: @user120404 I will answer in a few minutes, hold tight :D